# How to present a view on the top of the view controller when a button is click in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I wish to achieve a pop up view when a button is clicked. The pop up view contains some options through which the table view which is in the `ViewController` gets refreshed. Infact it is actually the filter option.
The screenshot shown is:

[image: How to achieve this. That is when the button is pressed the view appears which has the apps and games option and the background view becomes blur.]

Comment: Please post an answer or with a github repo.. I will surely support it.

Comment: You are searching for [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-alert-controller-in-ios-10-swift-3--cms-27589) probably.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Create a UIView with Button and hide it when you don't want to show it and show it when you want with or without animation. and refresh the tableview in button action method.

**Method 2:**

Cretae one more viewcontroller with background transparent and present it on the tableviewcotroller, then handle the button action through delegates.

**Blur VC background:**

```
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: How to blur the background of the view controller when the view appears??

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a view as subview. This will still allow user to interact with the other part of table view ( I meant superView ).
2. You can use a pop like how UIAlertview works, It uses separate window to show pop, unless user clicks on it you can't interact with other UI. Use can use some free components which are already available. you can refer [this link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=alert)

Answer (score -1):

Add pop up view on on top of the view.

Try something like:

Swift 3+

```
 self.view.addSubview(yourSubview)
```

or
 if the ad provider's view is not added to self.view but to something like [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow?

In Swift 3+:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: yourSubview)
```